# instance(object, type) returns True, should it not be False?

Tags: python

I thought in Python that:

- All classes ultimately are subclasses of object
- All classes utimately are instances of type
- object is an instance of type,
- and type is a subclass of object.

However after checking
`isinstance(object,type)` which returned `True` as expected. As object is an instance of type.

However I'm not sure why `isinstance(type,object)` returns `True`. (I thought this would be `False` as type isn't an instance of object).
Particularly as `isinstance(type,type)` is `True` ie it's an instance of itself.

And also `issubclass(object,type)` returns `False`, which was expected, but the results above `isinstance(type,object)` made me doubt wether I understood the relationships properly.

is it because isinstance works across subclasses but type doesn't?

Comment: "Everything is an object"? `type` is a class describing a type, and `object` is a class describing... well, an object, and every class should inherit from `object`, including `type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it because isinstance works across subclasses but type doesn't?

Exactly. `type(x)` gives you the actual type of *x*, whereas `isinstance(x, t)` checks whether the type of `x` is `t` *or a subclass of t*. Hence, `isinstance(x, t)` is `True` even when `type(x) == t` would not.

In particular, `object` is the base class from which all other classes inherit, thus `type`, i.e. `type(type)`, is also a subclass of `object` and `isinstance(type, object)` is true.